# Showing ImageView from another Activity

Tags: android, android-imageview

Is this possible to create a new Activity( Let's call it "ImageActivity" ) with  an ImageView element and in situation when i need to show the same image in many places( Activities ), just inherit this image from "ImageActivity" ?

Comment: Don't inherit, just open it as a new activity.

Comment: You cant call that Image in your current activity from previous activity. but you can call new activity as a dialog box and show that image .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i need to show the same image in many places( Activities )

You can use the same layout snippet to create the ImageView with identical settings in all of your Activities and pass the data pointing to the image in the Bundles that start each Activity.

Simply add the snippet to each Activity with `<merge>` or a LayoutInflater, and use an `R.drawable.*`, a local file, a URL, etc to load the same image into this layout.

Comment: Can I do the same for buttons?

Comment: Probably, I not certain what you are asking though.

Answer (score 1):

You can place the image in a standalone xml layout, and include that layout as part of all your Activities' layouts. [See here](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html) for more information.

Comment: If memory isn't a major problem (non huge amount of images) and it will be the same image then an include layout will work.